# Crear usuario de MySQL que no pueda ver las bases de datos por defecto

Tags: mysql

buenas estoy montando un servidor de MySQL y quiero crear un usuario que no pueda ni ver ni hacer operaciones con las bases de datos que vienen por defecto al crear el servidor.

Comment: Hola, tendrás que darle una repasada a [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html). Saludos

Comment: Si, eso ya me lo he mirado quiero que tenga permisos a todas las bases de datos excepto las que vienen por defecto (sys, information, mysql)...

Comment: usa revoke en las tablas que mensionas

Comment: No puedo hacer revoke a tablas que no tengo assignado permisos

Comment: con el usuario root o admin deberias poder

Answer (score 3):

Primero creas el usuario:

```
CREATE USER nombreusuario@'%' identified by 'estaeslacontraseña';
```

Lo que está entre comillas después del arroba, significa que el usuario puede acceder a la base de datos con cualquier `ip`.

Luego asignas los permisos:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON nombredelabasededatos.* to nombreusuario;
```

Con esta ultima linea le damos permiso `(SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)` al usuario `nombredeusuario`, solo para la base de datos `nombredelabasededatos`.

Te das cuenta que en al asignarle los permisos al usuario, ahí mismo restringimos la base de datos a la que puede acceder?, si quieres darle permiso al usuario para otras bases de datos, simplemente repites la linea cambiando el nombre de la base de datos.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Si eso ya lo vi, asi le das permisos a solo esa base de datos a mi lo que me gustaria es que pueda tener a todas las creen de ahora en adelante excepto las de sistema por defecto

Comment: No creo que se pueda. Además no me parece una buena práctica lo que quieres hacer.