# MySQL poner GRANT CREATE solo limitar a crear tablas y bases de datos

Tags: mysql

estoy creando un servidor MySQL y he creado un usuario y le he dado permisos para crear bases de datos y tablas, pero esto a la vez me incluye permisos para crear usuario o eliminarlo y no me interesa eso.

```
'GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER ON *.* TO `mysql`@`%`'
```

He estado probando de poner permisos y cuando doy permisos de INSERT este me permite crear usuarios.

Comment: y cuál es tu pregunta? No puedes crear tablas? Te da un error al crearlas? Las puedes crear pero no rellenar? Por favor, para que podamos ayudarte danos algo más de información y sobre todo, escribe tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Me permite crear bases de datos y tablas (quiero) , pero también me deja crear usuario y eliminar usuarios que eso no me interesa (no me interesa).

Comment: Hola, en tu [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279009/crear-usuario-de-mysql-que-no-pueda-ver-las-bases-de-datos-por-defecto) de ayer te sugerí que le dieras una repasada a GRANT, ahora te sugiero que le des una repasada a [ROLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html). Saludos

Comment: Como le diste permisos a ese usuario que creaste? Edita tu pregunta.

Comment: @Osubarudo Ya esta actualizado

Comment: Despues de *.* TO tienes que poner el nombre de usuario. Esto ya te lo dije en la respuesta a la pregunta anterior que hiciste.

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas y efectivamente permite crear usuarios, pero no asignarle privilegios, así que no es tan grave. Lo que me causa duda es ¿porque quieres crear un usuario con esos permisos?

Comment: Esa es mi pregunta que es muy extraño